# How can I make sure that a folder generated by task and used in srcSet configuration exists at the point when the compilation of sourceSet is started?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I have following setup:

```
val sourcePath by configurations.creating

tasks.register<Copy>("fetchSources") {
    from(zipTree(sourcePath.files.first()))
    into("${project.buildDir}/synced")
}

dependencies {
     sourcePath(group = "shabunc.org.app.runtime", name = "runtime", version = "0.0.1", classifier = "sources")
}

kotlin {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            kotlin.srcDir(tasks.named<Copy>("fetchSources").get().destinationDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Which is working perfectly well apart one thing: gradle do not know that Kotlin configuration depends on existence of the folder downloaded with "fetchResources" task.

In other words, I'm supposed to call `fetchResources` every time before building. I, of course, can also add fetchResources as a dependency to one of the build tasks, say `jsJar`. However I want to ask:

**Is there a way to guarantee that specific files will be present up to the moment when I'm building the project without explicitly introducing a task dependency but rather relying on tasks output somehow?**

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html), it seems like the only option different from tasks dependency is to add something like [onlyIf](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:onlyIf(groovy.lang.Closure))